# how to split one git repo into two without changing the history commit hash

Tags: git

I have a GIT repo like:

> ```
>                      / --- [lots of work] 
>                     /   
>  root --- ref_a --- .---- [ Lots of work ]
>
>         orphane commit 
>               based on ref_a--- [Lots ofworks]
>                             \ --- [lots of work]
> ```

I'd like to split this repo into two repo like

repo1:

> ```
>                      / --- [lots of work] 
>                     /   
>  root --- ref_a --- .---- [ Lots of work ]
> ```

repo2:

> ```
>         orphane commit 
>               based on ref_a--- [Lots ofworks]
>                             \ --- [lots of work]
> ```

And I'd like to keep all commit hash intact.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just work on another branch? copy whole repo in another folder?

Comment: folder? I don't want to change any code directory structure.

Comment: Clone the repository in two and delete the branch(es) you don't want in each repository? Or am I misunderstanding what you want? Commit SHA-1s only change if the commit or any of its ancestor commits change but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

```
                 / --- [lots of work] (branch1)
                /   
 root --- ref_a --- .---- [ Lots of work ] (branch2)

      orphane commit 
            based on ref_a--- [Lots ofworks] (branch3)
                          \ --- [lots of work] (branch4)
```

1. Copy the whole repository into a new folder (f.ex. your repo was in ~/myrepo and the new one will be in ~/newrepo)
2. In ~/myrepo delete branches branch3 and branch4; in ~/newrepo delete branches branch1 and branch2.
3. If you have remote repository you were pushing to from the original repo, do not forget to remove or update remote for the ~/newrepo.
4. Done. Later, Git GC will remove non-referenced commits, and hashes of existing commits will of course stay intact.

Comment: What if there are thousands of branches and tags? How can i distinguish them based on different root?

Comment: And if the repo has multiple roots (orphane commits), how to find them and separate them?

Comment: I apologize for me being late with the response. 
Of course, having thousands branches and tags will complicate matters, as you and only you must decide what to remove.
You can list all branches a commit belongs to with the following command: 
`git branch --contains <commit>`

Comment: For orphane commits – as long as you have their hashes, f.ex. retrieved via `git reflog --all`, you can add references (branches or tags) to them.